# Sorting array of coordinates by their Euclidean distance

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, distance

I have an array A of length x and an array of length y where y > x.

For example:

```
A = [[14,44],[16,47],[27,79]]
B = [[14,46],[16,46],[18,89],[27,79],[45,127]]
```

What I want for the output is the array sorted like that:

```
B = [[14,46],[16,46],[27,79],[15,89],[45,127]]
```

I want to sort the array B so that the lowest Euclidean distance of coordinates from A and B vectors are aligned (with a threshold to put the vectors of B which are not close to a vector of A, at the end of the vector B).

Here is my code:

```
def align_by_dist(A, B):
    for i in range(len(B)):
        D = []
        for j in range(len(A)):
            dist = distance.euclidean(A[j], B[i])
            if dist < 3: # Select a treshold for the euclidean distance
                D.append(dist) # Append the euclidean distance which is lower than the threshold
                if dist == min(D): # Check if it is the lower euclidean distance 
                    B[j], B[i] = B[i], B[j]
                # If it is the lowest euclidean distance, put at the same level in the array              
return A, B
```

My problem is that when I have close vectors like in my example, the first vector with a low euclidean distance but maybe not the lowest makes a sort to the B array.

Here is what my code produce:

```
B = [[16,46],[14,46],[27,79],[15,89],[45,127]]
```

The first vector and the second one should be inverted.

Answer (score 0):

I may have succeeded with this modification of my code:

```
def align_by_dist(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        D = [] # This list will contain the index where the euclidean distance is lower than the threshold
        for j in range(len(B)):
            dist = distance.euclidean(A[i], B[j]) # Compute the euclidean distance between a target at index j and a prediction at index I
            if dist <= 4: # Select a treshold for the euclidean distance
                D.append(np.array([dist,j,i])) # Append the euclidean distance and the index of the target and prediction vector
        if D: # If we find an euclidean distance lower than the threshold we can now sort for the index i the list of prediction
            D_sorted = sorted(D,key=lambda elem:elem[0]) # We sort the array of distance lower than the threshold to get the minimum distance for the index I 
            value = D_sorted[0]
            B[value[2].astype(np.int64)], B[value[1].astype(np.int64)] = B[value[1].astype(np.int64)], B[value[2].astype(np.int64)] # We updated the target list position 
            A[value[2].astype(np.int64)] = [1000000,1000000] # We set the value of the predictions very high to not have duplicates when sorting the targets coordinates 
return B
```

Comment: Running your code with your input arrays gives a duplicate point: `[[14.0, 46.0], [16.0, 46.0], [27.0, 79.0], [27.0, 79.0], [45.0, 127.0]]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using numpy already, let's try to come up with a vectorized solution. The squared Euclidean distance between two points is given by `d^2 = (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2`

```
A = np.array([[14.0,44],[16,47],[27,79]])
B = np.array([[14.0,46],[16,46],[18,89],[27,79],[45,127]])
```

`A[:, 0, None]` gives us all the X values of the points in `A`, as a `(3, 1)` shape array.
`B[:, 0, None].T` gives us all the Y values of the points in `B`, as a `(1, 5)` shape array.

Numpy can broadcast these shapes, so that `A[:, 0, None] - B[:, 0, None].T` gives us a `(3, 5)` shape array, where the `i, j` element is `A[i, 0] - B[0, j]`. Element-wise squaring that gives us the first term of our squared-Euclidean-distance formula. Doing the same thing with column `1` of `A` and `B` (instead of column 0) gives us the second term.

```
dist_sqr = (A[:, 0, None] - B[:, 0, None].T)**2 + (A[:, 1, None] - B[:, 1, None].T)**2
```

Now, `dist_sqr[i, j]` gives you the distance between the `A[i, :]` and `B[j, :]` points.

For each point in `A` (for each row), the column containing the smallest distance indicates the closest point of `B`.

To select the column index of the smallest distance, we use `np.argmin()` with `axis=1`.

```
min_dist_pt = np.argmin(dist_sqr, axis=1)
```

This gives us a 3-element vector `array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64)`.

```
reordered_B = B[min_dist_pt, :]

# array([[14., 46.],
#       [16., 46.],
#       [27., 79.]])
```

This is the order we want.
Now, we need to fill in the remaining points from B. It looks like you don't have an order in mind, so I'll just fill them in order of their occurrence in `B`. To do this, I convert `range(num_pts)` and `min_dist_pt` to sets, and then take the set-difference.

```
num_pts = B.shape[0]
remaining_indices = list(set(range(num_pts)) - set(min_dist_pt))
remaining_B = B[remaining_indices, :]

# array([[ 18.,  89.],
#       [ 45., 127.]])
```

Finally, we stack the `reordered_B` and `remaining_B` arrays:

```
np.vstack((reordered_B, remaining_B))

# array([[ 14.,  46.],
#       [ 16.,  46.],
#       [ 27.,  79.],
#       [ 18.,  89.],
#       [ 45., 127.]])
```

---

All together as a single function:

```
def align_by_dist_2(A, B):
    A = np.asarray(A, np.float64)
    B = np.asarray(B, np.float64)
    
    dist_sqr = (A[:, 0, None] - B[:, 0, None].T)**2 + (A[:, 1, None] - B[:, 1, None].T)**2
    
    min_dist_pt = np.argmin(dist_sqr, axis=1)
    
    reordered_B = B[min_dist_pt, :]
    
    num_pts = B.shape[0]
    remaining_indices = list(set(range(num_pts)) - set(min_dist_pt))
    remaining_B = B[remaining_indices, :]
    
    return np.vstack((reordered_B, remaining_B))
```

Running some comparison between your loopy approach (`align_by_dist`) and my vectorized approach (`align_by_dist_2`):

```
A = np.array([[14.0,44],[16,47],[27,79]])
B = np.array([[14.0,46],[16,46],[18,89],[27,79],[45,127]])

%timeit align_by_dist(A, B)
210 µs ± 6.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit align_by_dist_2(A, B)
45.3 µs ± 6.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

shows a speedup of ~5x with the vectorized approach

With a larger array:

```
A = np.random.random((100, 2))
B = np.random.random((110, 2))

%timeit align_by_dist(A, B)
189 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit align_by_dist_2(A, B)
227 µs ± 27.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

With a bigger array, the speedup is even more: ~800x!